# Question mark instead of Icon in react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator, react-native-vector-icons

I installed vector icons by following command :

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

Then imported icons by this method:( I am not using expo)

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

This is the main code:

```
const MainTab=()=>{

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return(

<Tab.Navigator

screenOptions={({route})=>({
 tabBarIcon:({color, size})=>{
  let iconName;

  if (route.name=='Home') {

    iconName='ios-home'

  }else if(route.name=='Settings'){

  iconName='logo-settings'
 }

 return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
 }
})

>


<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SecondPage} />


</Tab.Navigator>
  )}
```

It's showing up question mark instead icons

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: 'ios-home' appears to be a valid name, but I don't see a 'logo-settings' icon specified [here](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Comment: Issue is not about the names, I tried several names and result was same

Comment: Can you post up an Expo Snack that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I am not using expo

Comment: Ah, that image looked like it was from Expo. You may still be able to create a Snack however. Any online sandbox that can handle RN would do IMO.

Comment: add this line in adroid/app/build.gradle 
 ```apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"```

Comment: try to link react-native-vector-icons and build with android studio and try to run

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha I added but nothing changed

Comment: @MayankPandav I am using react native version '0.61.5'.  It's auto linking

Comment: try to do manually linking of that library in your android studio

Answer (score 1):

This issue is causing because your icon's name is not being matched up with icons in the library. Try using different icon types and names.
For your current code replacing 
`iconName='ios-home'`
 with
    `iconName='home'`
 and 
`iconName='logo-settings'`
 with 
`iconName='settings'`
 may work.

You can also try this using different icon library

```
import icon from fontAwesome5
```

`<Icon name='home'/>` and `<Icon name='cog'/>`

You can find the list of icons for [fontAwesome here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery).

Comment: I tried several names from library but issue is persisting, My react native version is "0.61.5", Seems like the library is not compatible with latest react native version

Comment: Buddy i really appreciate you, I was struggling three days with this issue, Finally your solution fixed it, ( i mean the fontawesome method), Please write your comment as answer i will vote for it. And one more question where can i get the complete list of name these icons because when i inserted ```apple-pay``` it doesn't show up but ```home``` and ```cog``` worked

Answer (score 1):

follow this below link, this will give you the websites where it gets the Icons from.

```
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#bundled-icon-sets
```

`ios-home` and `logo-settings` are not part of `Ionicons` that is why you are getting ? symbol.

Comment: I replaced ```ios-home``` with ```home``` but nothing changed. Seems like version 5 react-navigation has incompatibility with react native version is "0.61.5

Answer (score 0):

Icons are actually fonts, with pictures replacing characters. You get those symbols because the browser doesn't recognize the font, and doesn't have any printable character to go with that.

You need to drag the font into your project's public folder so the browser can download it from your server. The docs explain how here:

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/README.md#bundled-icon-sets

This will allow you to use your originally chosen icon names like "ios-something"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but using react-native-navigation, I was getting squares with question marks inside in my navigation bar. It only affected Android, and seemingly only affected icons I tried to load using getImageSource().

What solved my issue was to uninstall the apk and add it again (apparently due to font caching, as found in a comment here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1117)

The simple question mark, as others pointed out, is caused by giving an incorrect icon name.